# Why are @NgAttr etc. deprecated?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

In angular 0.10.0, @NgAttr, @NgCallback, @NgOneWay, @NgOneWayOneTime, and @NgTwoWay are all deprecated.  What should they be replaced with, and why?